# create list that float elements to right on reaching bottom of div (and div width adjust automatic)

Tags: html, containers

Hopefully this is pretty simple but I couldn't work it out yet.

I have container and list structure like so:

```
<aside id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <li>
        etc...
    </ul>
</aside>
```

what I need is to have the li elements list vertically as they do now, but once they arrive at the bottom of the aside container element (height: 500px for example) the following li elements float to the right. How do I do this (without tables!)? Basically, the endresult I need is: to have a list of titles fall vertically and then float to right (the container is horizontal), creating a new column. And then the aside container div to adjust the width automatically.

I'll be uploading new titles to this every so on, so I need it to be capable of growing horizontally.

All help is welcome!
thanks!

Comment: Can you use CSS columns [like this example](http://jsbin.com/liguri/3/edit)?

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I didn't know about column-count. One new thing learned today! Could this be open ended instead of having specified number of columns?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Is that the affect you are after though? We can look at other methods.

Comment: For instance, we could use a [flexbox layout like this example](http://jsbin.com/hojaba/1/edit). You can add as many items as you want and the container will evenly align them. This is dependant on [browser support required though](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the flex box. It seems to work great, and hopefully the browser fallback won't be that bad for what I need. But there's one thing I'm missing: depending on the height, the li elements overflow the container - how do I adjust the container in order to avoid the overflow?

Comment: Could you show me an example with this problem? I think using `max-width` instead of `width` fixes this.

Comment: This is perhaps confusing to explain, but the only problem now is that the li items appear over the div that I have to the left of this flex list...I have removed all z-indexes and have tried to play with the lu container width...

Comment: No problem. Can you add the html / css to the question? I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you'll have here is that you want the list read from top to bottom and then grow horizontally.  You could use the `column-count` CSS property but this would mean using a fixed number of columns which wouldn't immediately satisfy your needs.  I'm not sure there is a pure CSS method to achieve this but what you could do is use some simple JavaScript to determine to number of columns you'll need (total number of items / number of items that fit into 500px) and then dynamically add\amend the `column-count` CSS property.

Note that the `column-count` property won't work for IE versions < 10.

Here's a simple [working example](http://jsbin.com/fewukazuqupa/1/edit).

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I didn't know about column-count. One new thing learned today! Could this be open ended instead of having specified number of columns?

Comment: No, it has to be fixed.  If you want it dynamic you'll have to use a JS implementation like I have in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flexbox example from the comments.

- `.container` is given `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`
- The height of the container determines how many rows there are. Ensure that this px height equals `item height * number of rows`

[Here is a very good flexbox guide over on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #e91e63;
  height: 190px;
}
.container li {
  background: #9c27b0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "The height of the container determines how many rows there are. Ensure that this px height equals `item height * number of rows`" - I thinks that might address your overflow issue.